# Uneven column width

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to copy this table format.

[image]

but I can't seem to make
uneven column width for each td and it break the form of my table as well
here is my code:

```
<div class="CenterThings">
    <table class="CenterThings">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color:black;color:white;">Job Quotation</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 328px">Address:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="255px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 219px">Contact#:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 328px">
                Job Description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 328px">
                Printing Process:
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="195px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color:black;color:white;">Specification</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 328px">
                Quantity: 
            </td>
            <td style="width: 219px">
                Size:
            </td>
            <td>
                No.of pages inside: 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 328px">
                Material: 
            </td>
            <td style="width: 219px">
                Cover: 
            </td>
            <td>
                Inside: 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is its output : [image]
I needed to somehow replicate the first picture or somehow close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested tables, placing a whole table inside a TD. This would allow the extra complexity in your layout.

```
<table id='main_table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <table id='inner_table'>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```